# expect(path).to.be.a.file() fails to compile with "Property 'file' does not exist on type 'TypeComparison'"

Tags: typescript, path, node-modules, chai

In a Mocha test suite I want to assert that a file exists and I thought I could use the chai-fs module to do so:

```
const pathToCheck = path.join(rootPath, '../somePath');
expect(pathToCheck).to.be.a.file();
```

My IDE complains about the `file` porting of this code with:

> [ts] Property 'file' does not exist on type 'TypeComparison'.

However when I ignore the error and run the encompassing test anyway, it passes (and fails if I pass it a nonsense path). This causes my CI pipeline to fail etc. **How do I fix this?** I've ensured I'm using the latest versions of the node modules involved.

`(pathToCheck).should.be.a.file()` also fails for the same reason.

Comment: Without using chai-fs, I managed to get fs.existsSync(pathToCheck).should.be.true to work, but I'd still be interested in understanding why the above doesn't compile.

Comment: Check chai's (expect / should) [documentation](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/). It doesn't compile because there is no "file" function in chai's api.

Comment: you're right! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check chai's (expect / should) documentation. It doesn't compile because there is no "file" function in chai's api. :)